# Axis2 Random Web Service Names

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

I created an Axis2 web service that fetches geocoding information from PitneyBowes and returns the data to the original requester. It appears to be working, as the data is returned fine. However, each call I make seems to create a new web service entry on the listServices page. The web service name will be the same as the original name, but with a random number after it.

For example, if I start Axis2 fresh and go to the listServices page, I will see:

**GeoCodeService**

If I then use SoapUI to call the service and then refresh the listServices page, I see:

**GeoCodeService**

**GeocodeUSAddress1439922765370_1**

Another request and refresh will display:

**GeoCodeService**

**GeocodeUSAddress1439922765370_1**

**GeocodeUSAddress1439923207473_2**

Has anyone seen this issue before? Thanks in advance.

**Update**
It looks like the number may be a timestamp followed by a sequence starting from "1".

Answer (score 0):

We eventually figured out this is done by design in the classes generated from WSDL2JAVA. What were were forgetting is that there is a cleanup() method that needs to be called after making the web service call. So it would be something like this (pseudo code):

```
GeocodeUSAddressStub geocodeUSAddress = new GeocodeUSAddressStub();    
GeocodeResponse response = geocodeUSAddress.geocodeUSAddress(requestData);
geocodeUSAddress.cleanup();
```